# initialize a structure in constructor initializer list in C++

Tags: c++, constructor, initializer

// I have a structure

```
 typedef struct
 {
    uint8_t* data;
    uint16_t data_ln;
 } Struc_Data;
```

//a derived type from this struct

```
 Struc_Data    tx_struct;
```

// i have to initialize this 'tx_struct' in constructor initializer list, i am not getting how

```
 Constr::Constr( ):
    tx_struct  (reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(nullptr), 0U)  //this does not work
 {

 }
```

Comment: What you've failed to do is show us Constr, and how you've left a declaration for Struct_Data out of its definition.  Could you post the whole code?  Its not that large.

Answer (score 2):

`Struc_Data` is an aggregate, so value-initialization will do if you want to zero-initialize the members:

```
Constr::Constr( ): tx_struct() {} // or tx_struct{}
```

Otherwise, use curly-brace initialization:

```
Constr::Constr( ): tx_struct{nullptr, 42U} {}
```

Here's a simplified, compiling example:

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct
{
  uint8_t* data;
  uint16_t data_ln;
} Struc_Data;

struct Foo
{
  Foo() : tx_struct{nullptr, 0U} {}
  Struc_Data tx_struct;
};
```

Note that in C++ it is unusual to use the `typedef` syntax for class definitions. The preferred form is

```
struct Struc_Data { .... };
```

Comment: Thanks jaunchopanza but its Not working with m_tx_struct{}, tx_struct() {} OR m_tx_struct {reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(nullptr), 0U} {}. What i tried earlier 'tx_struct  (reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(nullptr), 0U)', something is missing here itself :(

Comment: @learningfellow What is not working and who told you to use `reinterpret_cast`?

Comment: @ juanchopanza:  reinterpret_cast is used here to initialize the uint8_t* pointer to nullptr. We may not use it. Simply keeping 'tx_struct (nullptr, 0U) {}', code does not compile.

Comment: @learningfellow Then maybe your compiler does not support these C++11 features. The first variant should work pre-C++11. And you don't need `reinterpret_cast`. Note that the example I posted compiles with gcc 4.8.1.

Comment: May be. I am using IAR compiler. with 'm_tx_struct ( nullptr, 0U )' i get two errors " Error[Pe415]: no suitable constructor exists to convert from int to "Struc_Data" 
Error[Pe018]: expected a ") "

Comment: @learningfellow OK, well, `nullptr` is C++11, and so is the curly brace initialization in the constructor initialization list. But if you just need to zero-initialize the struct's members, then use the first version I posted.

Comment: Thanks juanchopanza but No, i have tried that too. I am very close with "tx_struct() ( nullptr, 0U )". one error remains Error[Pe130]: expected a "{". Tried {} with many combinations :P Wondering where it is required :(

Comment: @learningfellow If the first version doesn't work, then your compiler isn't even C++03 compliant WRT this very basic feature. It will be very hard to *guess* what will work for you without good knowledge of that particular compiler. Both code samples I provided are valid C++, but the second one requires C++11.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

1. Change the C style struct to a C++ style struct.
2. Define a constructor with the required arguments.

   ```
   struct Struc_Data
   {
     Struc_Data(uint8_t* data1, uint16_t data2) : data(data1), data_In(data2) {}
     uint8_t* data;
     uint16_t data_ln;
   };
   ```

Comment: It's not an anonymous `struct`. It just uses C-style `typedef` syntax.

Comment: @juanchopanza Per my understanding, it is anonymous struct since there is no name before the '{`. Perhaps I am mistaken.

Comment: You could be right, but to me an anonymous struct really has no name. For example `struct {int i, double x} data;`. Here `data` is an instance of an anonymous struct.

Comment: I am not allowed to change the struct in this case, it belongs to the stack bought. I am initializing in the Constructor Initializer list because PC-lint want it :(